# How to increase the speed to convert speech to text in android?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am trying to convert the speech to text in android.In my project i am having two buttons namely **Record** and **Stop**.
If i click the record button the speech will be recorded from the user, after triggering the stop button recorded speech will be saved in FLAC format and then that sound will be send to Google API for transcription[ie., speech to text]
Well it is working fine, but it is taking much more time to convert the speech to text if the speech is too large.
Can any one please tell me how to increase the speed and performance of to show the text as soon as possible?

Suggestion please.

Thanks for your precious time!..

*Please find the source for reference*

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


String str_RecordFailed = "RECORD_FAILED";


// Language spoken
// Obs: It requires Google codes: English(en_us), Portuguese(pt_br), Spanish
// (es_es), etc
String language = "en_us";

// Key obtained through Google Developer group
String api_key = "AIzaSyBgnC5fljMTmCFeilkgLsOKBvvnx6CBS0M";

// Name of the sound file (.flac)
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/recording.flac";

// URL for Google API
String root = "https://www.google.com/speech-api/full-duplex/v1/";
String dwn = "down?maxresults=1&pair=";
String API_DOWN_URL = root + dwn;
String up_p1 = "up?lang=" + language
        + "&lm=dictation&client=chromium&pair=";
String up_p2 = "&key=";



// Variables used to establish return code
private static final long MIN = 10000000;
private static final long MAX = 900000009999999L;
long PAIR;

// Constants
private int mErrorCode = -1;
private static final int DIALOG_RECORDING_ERROR = 0;
// Rate of the recorded sound file
int sampleRate;
// Recorder instance
private Recorder mRecorder;

// Output for Google answer
TextView txtView;
Button recordButton, stopButton;//, listenButton;

// Handler used for sending request to Google API
Handler handler = new Handler();

// Recording callbacks
private Handler mRecordingHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    public boolean handleMessage(Message m) {
        switch (m.what) {
        case FLACRecorder.MSG_AMPLITUDES:
            FLACRecorder.Amplitudes amp = (FLACRecorder.Amplitudes) m.obj;

            break;

        case FLACRecorder.MSG_OK:
            // Ignore
            break;

        case Recorder.MSG_END_OF_RECORDING:

            break;

        default:
            mRecorder.stop();
            mErrorCode = m.what;
            showDialog(DIALOG_RECORDING_ERROR);
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }
});

// DOWN handler
Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 1: // GET DOWNSTREAM json id="@+id/comment"
            String mtxt = msg.getData().getString("text");
            if (mtxt.length() > 20) {
                final String f_msg = mtxt;
                handler.post(new Runnable() { // This thread runs in the UI
                    // TREATMENT FOR GOOGLE RESPONSE
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String msg = null;
                        System.out.println("===transcript  "+f_msg);
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(f_msg);
                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                            jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(0);
                            JSONArray array2 =jsonObject.getJSONArray("alternative");
                            jsonObject = array2.getJSONObject(0);
                            msg = jsonObject.getString("transcript");
                            System.out.println("===transcript  "+msg);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 

                        txtView.setText(msg);
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        }
    }
}; // doDOWNSTRM Handler end

// UPSTREAM channel. its servicing a thread and should have its own handler
Handler messageHandler2 = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 1: // GET DOWNSTREAM json
            Log.d("ParseStarter", msg.getData().getString("post"));
            break;
        case 2:
            Log.d("ParseStarter", msg.getData().getString("post"));
            break;
        }

    }
}; // UPstream handler end

/**************************************************************************************************************
 * Implementation
 **/


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
    recordButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.record);
    stopButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stopButton.setEnabled(false);
//      listenButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.listen);
//      listenButton.setEnabled(false);

    mRecorder = new Recorder(this, mRecordingHandler);

}

/***************************************************************************************************************
 * Method related to recording in FLAC file
 */

/*Thread th = new Thread()
{

    public void run() {



    };
};*/


public void recordButton(View v) {

    mRecorder.start(fileName);

    txtView.setText("");
    recordButton.setEnabled(false);
    stopButton.setEnabled(true);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    /*sampleRate = mRecorder.mFLACRecorder.getSampleRate();
    getTranscription(sampleRate);
    mRecorder.stop();*/

}

/***************************************************************************************************************
 * Method that stops recording
 */

public void stopRecording(View v) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        sampleRate = mRecorder.mFLACRecorder.getSampleRate();
        getTranscription(sampleRate);
        mRecorder.stop();

        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        recordButton.setEnabled(true);
}

/***************************************************************************************************************
 * Method that listens to recording
 */
public void listenRecord(View v) {
    Context context = this;

    FLACPlayer mFlacPlayer = new FLACPlayer(context, fileName);
    mFlacPlayer.start();

}

      /**************************************************************************************************************
 * Method related to Google Voice Recognition
 **/

public void getTranscription(int sampleRate) {

    File myfil = new File(fileName);
    if (!myfil.canRead())
    {
        Log.d("ParseStarter", "FATAL no read access");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry :  Unable to convert the recorded voice", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    // first is a GET for the speech-api DOWNSTREAM
    // then a future exec for the UPSTREAM / chunked encoding used so as not
    // to limit
    // the POST body sz

    PAIR = MIN + (long) (Math.random() * ((MAX - MIN) + 1L));
    // DOWN URL just like in curl full-duplex example plus the handler
    downChannel(API_DOWN_URL + PAIR, messageHandler);

    // UP chan, process the audio byteStream for interface to UrlConnection
    // using 'chunked-encoding'
    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(myfil);
        FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel(); // Get the file's size and then
                                            // map it into memory
        int sz = (int) fc.size();
        MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, sz);
        byte[] data2 = new byte[bb.remaining()];
        Log.d("ParseStarter", "mapfil " + sz + " " + bb.remaining());
        bb.get(data2);
        // conform to the interface from the curl examples on full-duplex
        // calls
        // see curl examples full-duplex for more on 'PAIR'. Just a globally
        // uniq value typ=long->String.
        // API KEY value is part of value in UP_URL_p2
        upChannel(root + up_p1 + PAIR + up_p2 + api_key, messageHandler2,
                data2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void downChannel(String urlStr, final Handler messageHandler) {

    final String url = urlStr;

    new Thread() {
        Bundle b;

        public void run() {
            String response = "NAO FOI";
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.what = 1;
            // handler for DOWN channel http response stream - httpsUrlConn
            // response handler should manage the connection.... ??
            // assign a TIMEOUT Value that exceeds by a safe factor
            // the amount of time that it will take to write the bytes
            // to the UPChannel in a fashion that mimics a liveStream
            // of the audio at the applicable Bitrate. BR=sampleRate * bits
            // per sample
            // Note that the TLS session uses
            // "* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1): "
            // to wake up the listener when there are additional bytes.
            // The mechanics of the TLS session should be transparent. Just
            // use
            // httpsUrlConn and allow it enough time to do its work.
            Scanner inStream = openHttpsConnection(url);
            // process the stream and store it in StringBuilder
            while (inStream.hasNextLine()) {
                b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("text", inStream.nextLine());
                msg.setData(b);
                messageHandler.dispatchMessage(msg);
            }

        }
    }.start();
}

private void upChannel(String urlStr, final Handler messageHandler,
        byte[] arg3) {

    final String murl = urlStr;
    final byte[] mdata = arg3;
    Log.d("ParseStarter", "upChan " + mdata.length);
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            String response = "NAO FOI";
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.what = 2;
            Scanner inStream = openHttpsPostConnection(murl, mdata);
            inStream.hasNext();
            // process the stream and store it in StringBuilder
            while (inStream.hasNextLine()) {
                response += (inStream.nextLine());
                Log.d("ParseStarter", "POST resp " + response.length());
            }
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("post", response);
            msg.setData(b);
            // in.close(); // mind the resources
            messageHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        }
    }.start();

}

// GET for DOWNSTREAM
private Scanner openHttpsConnection(String urlStr) {
    InputStream in = null;
    int resCode = -1;
    Log.d("ParseStarter", "dwnURL " + urlStr);

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(urlConn instanceof HttpsURLConnection)) {
            throw new IOException("URL is not an Https URL");
        }

        HttpsURLConnection httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection) urlConn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        // TIMEOUT is required
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        httpConn.connect();

        resCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (resCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            return new Scanner(httpConn.getInputStream());
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

// GET for UPSTREAM
private Scanner openHttpsPostConnection(String urlStr, byte[] data) {
    InputStream in = null;
    byte[] mextrad = data;
    int resCode = -1;
    OutputStream out = null;
    // int http_status;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(urlConn instanceof HttpsURLConnection)) {
            throw new IOException("URL is not an Https URL");
        }

        HttpsURLConnection httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection) urlConn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "audio/x-flac; rate="
                + sampleRate);
        httpConn.connect();

        try {
            // this opens a connection, then sends POST & headers.
            out = httpConn.getOutputStream();
            // Note : if the audio is more than 15 seconds
            // dont write it to UrlConnInputStream all in one block as this
            // sample does.
            // Rather, segment the byteArray and on intermittently, sleeping
            // thread
            // supply bytes to the urlConn Stream at a rate that approaches
            // the bitrate ( =30K per sec. in this instance ).
            Log.d("ParseStarter", "IO beg on data");
            out.write(mextrad); // one big block supplied instantly to the
                                // underlying chunker wont work for duration
                                // > 15 s.
            Log.d("ParseStarter", "IO fin on data");
            // do you need the trailer?
            // NOW you can look at the status.
            resCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

            Log.d("ParseStarter", "POST OK resp "
                    + httpConn.getResponseMessage().getBytes().toString());

            if (resCode / 100 != 2) {
                Log.d("ParseStarter", "POST bad io ");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ParseStarter", "FATAL " + e);

        }

        if (resCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.d("ParseStarter", "OK RESP to POST return scanner ");
            return new Scanner(httpConn.getInputStream());
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}}
```

Comment: This idea might not totally solve your problem, but depending on your needs you might extract the voice conversion into an AsyncTask and thereby prevent the Application from freezing. I think this won't change the speed of conversion (at least I see no reason for an increase), therefore I just suggest this as a comment.

Comment: If you're willing to sacrifice accuracy, segment the recording into 10second samples and submit each sample to google as soon as you get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On same concept am working and same thing is happening with me in different manner. i mean when am trying to record audio more than 40 second it is not giving me output . But below than 40 sec it gives me proper output when recording length is high it mean your FLAC file size is big thats why it takes time so as per my research i found way to reduce the size of recording file by changing frequency of recording but there is disadvantage of it when you decrease the frequency the result may vary i mean it may not be accurate as compare to high frequency recording clip

so here is my suggestion to you to increase performance (But result will may varies due to this suggestion)

go into **FLACRecorder.java** file and in run() method use this line

```
final int sample_rates[] = { 8000 };
```

instead of

```
 final int sample_rates[] = { 44100, 22050, 11025, 8000 };
```

it means During recording your sample rate will be 8000 which is very low so your recorded file size will be low and due to this it will fastly get uploaded on google server for voice recognition and performance will get improve hope this will help you

Comment: If i follow your suggestion,even it couldn't able to catch the single word from the user,which means its displayin nothing text

Comment: u tried if not then try it then reply me i already tried and it gave me result please try it you may have 2,3 options too you can use 22050/11025 also to reduce size of file

Comment: if i use 11025,yeah performance is litle bit better..Thanks for your concern.

Comment: i got one more question,can you please tell me, how to find if the speech didn't catch properly?